# Jquery validation does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

For eg:I have two fields here. If I fill input type="second" and post it and If I do not fill input type = first, it is not validating first field,it should tell me to fill first field but vice versa if I fill input type = first and if I do not input type = second, it is showing error.

```
<form name="test" onsubmit="return te()" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="first">
    <span id="">
    <input type="text" id="second">
    <span id="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
```

Comment: `lenght !== length` and `$(this).length` doesn't make sense,

Comment: selectors need to be strings.

Comment: Can you write error here.. for more understanding

Comment: @ahren:It was a typo, What else is wrong here ?

Comment: @Amit Agrawal: What is not clear, let me know, I will explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function te() {
var valid = true;

if ($('#first').val() =="")     
        valid = false;         
if ($('#second').val( == "") 
        valid = false;
if(valid == false)
 $("#error").text('Fill all required fields')    
    return valid;
}




<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <form name="test" onsubmit="return te()" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="first">
    <span id="">
    <input type="text" id="second">
    <span id="">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    <script>
    function te() {
         var valid = true;

           if ($('#first').val() =="")     
             valid = false;         
          if ($('#second').val() == "") 
           valid = false;
         if(valid == false)
            $("#error").text('Fill all required fields')    
        return valid;
    }


    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each field has a different validation, How can I use if(valid == false) to show error message. Can you tell me, what is wrong in my code.

Comment: @ram no problem with our code.But it looks like cleaner code.If you want different messages you need to do like that only

Comment: @ram but the condition to check empty use my condition

Comment: here valid is local variable

Comment: $('#second').val() == ""  use this

Comment: :Instead of length, you are asking me to get value and check if it is empty or not right.

Comment: :Each one here is asking me to do some thing which is not working.Can you show my mistake in my code and a working there.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong, may be that's the cause of error..

```
$(#first).val())
```

change it to

```
$("#first").val())
```

&

```
$(#second).val()
```

change to

```
$("#second").val()
```

if not, check console for error.